# How to change a property in for loop

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I have 12 `controls` and I want to change their value in for loop. I have tried many method but I can't solve this problem.

Here is my code:

```
Dim serviceNames() As String = {"Security Manager Remote Recorder", _
  "Security Manager Filter", "Security Manager Prob", _
  "Security Manager Intelligence", "Security Manager Maintenance", _
  "Security Manager Action", "Security Manager Agent Check", _
  "Security Manager Control", "Security Manager Deploy Copy", _
  "Security Manager Monitor", "Security Manager Reloader", _
  "Security Manager Schedule"}
Dim swButtons() = {sw0.Value, sw1.Value, sw2.Value, sw3.Value, sw4.Value, _
  sw5.Value, sw6.Value, sw7.Value, sw8.Value, sw9.Value, sw10.Value, sw11.Value}

For q As Integer = 0 To serviceNames.Count - 1
    Dim regService = My.Computer.Registry.GetValue( _
       "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\" + _
       serviceNames(q) + "", "Start", "")

    If regService = 2 Then
        swButtons(q) = True
    End If

    If regService = 4 Then
        MetroTabItem5.Text = "bu 4"
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Explain your question clearly ?

Comment: ok so i have 12 button placed windows forms and i want create for loop  then start 1 to 12 button enabled property to false in for loop. sorry my english not enough for clearly explain this problem. thx.

Comment: What type is `swButtons()`?  Are they buttons?  What is `sw0.Value`, `sw1.Value`, etc?  In other words, how are `sw0.Value` and the others defined?

Comment: Are you looking for `swButtons(q).IsEnabled = True`?

Comment: Im also confused what are u trying to do? Nico Schertler 's questn is what I wanted to ask too. A little more insight please

Comment: swX is a switchbutton this component http://www.devcomponents.com/dotnetbar/SwitchButtonControl.aspx this address i guess explain i have 12 windows service when form load event start i want to check if service startup disabled sw button value change to false for loop working good but i cannot change switchbutton value to false or true myserice list in array and i want to try make switchbutton.value a member of array after i want to use in for loop my problem swbutton(every button check and change).value = true thanks for help

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to set a property (here the `.Value` property of the button) to all your `buttons` (`swButtons`).

Declare an array of ***your component*** instead of an array of their ***value***:

```
Dim swButtons() As DevComponents.DotNetBar.Controls.SwitchButton = _
     {sw0, sw1, sw2, sw3, sw4, sw5, sw6, sw7, sw8, sw9, sw10, sw11}
```

Then you can easily iterate like this:

```
For Each item As DevComponents.DotNetBar.Controls.SwitchButton In swButtons
     item.Value = True
Next
```

Or if you want to change a single value of one button in your loop based on the index `q` you can access the button like this:

```
swButtons(q).Value = True
```

Comment: thank yourThank you very much for your information. I want to do what they say reached by applying. I'm so sorry for my english is bad. Be good to yourself.